# How to make a ball with a face texture on it?

Tags: texturing

[image]I want to achieve this 3D model in which a cartoon face is painted over the ball. I have tried making the texture but it doesn't seem realistic

This is what I have achieved [image]

Comment: Hello please show what you've tried so far and maybe share your file

Comment: I have overlayed the PNG provided over a Ball Texture

Comment: Please tell us **exactly** what you find unsatisfactory about your version

Comment: What @RobinBetts says. You asked "How to make a ball with a face texture on it?" and you achieved that already. Seems to me like an artistic question. First thing to notice is your image has no prominent lighting like the reference, so you could add that and check if your ball surface also provides this little plastic dots bump effect.

Comment: The reference image looks like it's painted over the ball, My image looks a bit burnt the colors do pop

Comment: @JudeMenezes Then maybe it's a problem with how you have combined the face texture with the general ball material. "Overlayed" is a bit vague and could have been achieved in different ways. But unfortunately you do not show the material setup either.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved the look by using a base image along with a height map
Here is the result and node setup.

[image]
[image]